# When do you embed mutex in struct in Go?

Tags: go, struct, embed, mutex

NOTE: I found the word 'embed' in the title was bad choice, but I will keep it.

I see a lot of code does like this:

```
type A struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    ...
}
```

And use it like this:

```
a := &A{}

a.mu.Lock()
defer a.mu.Unlock()

a.Something()
```

Is it better than local mutex or global mutex?

```
a := &A{}

var mu sync.Mutex
mu.Lock()
defer mu.Unlock()

a.Something()
```

When should I use former, or later?

Comment: Your first example doesn't work, because you can't call the method expression on A without an explicit receiver. If you're asking about using a single mutex per struct instance, or a single global mutex; do you need global mutex or do you want to lock each instance individually? It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my code.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's good practice to keep the mutex close to the data it is destined to protect. If a mutex ought to protect concurrent access to fields of a struct value, it's very convenient to add the mutex as a field of that struct, so its purpose is obvious.

If in your app there is only a single "instance" of `A`, it's fine to make the mutex a global variable too.

If your app is to create multiple values of `A`, all of which needs to be protected from concurrent access (but only individually, multiple values may be accessed concurrently), then obviously a global mutex is a bad choice, it would limit the concurrent access to a single value of `A` in any point in time.

Adding the mutex to the struct as a field, you will *naturally* have a separate mutex for each distinct struct values, responsible to guard that single, wrapper struct value (or its fields).

Although adding a mutex as in your example is not embedding, it's a regular, named field. An [embedded field declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) omits the field name.

It's known and used to a lesser extent, but it's also handy that you can "truly" embed a mutex in a struct, and you can call `Lock()` and `Unlock()` as if they would be part of the struct itself. It looks like this:

```
var hits struct {
    sync.Mutex
    n int
}

hits.Lock()
hits.n++
hits.Unlock()
```

(This example is taken from [10 things you (probably) don't know about Go, slide #3](https://talks.golang.org/2012/10things.slide#3).)

Comment: Some times I am sad that I could not add 10 or 50 likes per message. When found some hidden syntax of a language it usually such joy to found explanation and links to the official documentation of this language. Even Golang has such syntax entities, other language has much more.

Comment: It is important never to copy the `hits` variable, correct?

Comment: @TorstenBronger Yes, a mutex must not be copied. If you need to pass `hits` around, make it a pointer and pass the pointer.