# Can I use *sync.Mutex as an object specific variable?

Tags: go, struct, locking, mutex, goroutine

I want to make my program more efficient:
can I give a `*sync.Mutex` variable to a struct so that when I execute a `obj.Mutex.Lock()` it is locking just goroutines operation on that specific object?

example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type mystruct struct {
    Counter int
    Mutex   *sync.Mutex
}

func (obj *mystruct) incrementCount() {
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        obj.Mutex.Lock()
        obj.Counter++
        time.Sleep(time.Microsecond)
        obj.Mutex.Unlock()
    }
    fmt.Println("incrementCount returns")
}

func funcNotSensibleToMutex() {
    n := 0
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        n++
        time.Sleep(time.Microsecond)
    }
    fmt.Println("returns first since it's not affected by mutex")
}

func main() {
    a := &mystruct{0, &sync.Mutex{}}
    go a.incrementCount()
    go a.incrementCount()
    go funcNotSensibleToMutex()

    time.Sleep(time.Duration(5) * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("a counter", a.Counter)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because whenever I set a Lock on any mutex all variables are Locked?

That wouldn't make any sense. A mutex holds the locking state. Calling its `Lock()` and `Unlock()` methods synchronize goroutines based on its state. Separate mutex values have separate, distinct states.

It's completely normal and common to add mutex to a struct, you may even embed it: [When do you embed mutex in struct in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949467/when-do-you-embed-mutex-in-struct-in-go/44950096#44950096) The effect is what you'd expect: the mutex can be used to protect concurrent access to the containing struct value, but other struct values are not effected. 2 concurrent goroutines may update 2 separate struct values, but no more than 1 goroutine will access the same struct value at the same time.