# Go test hangs when using Mutex Lock and Unlock

Tags: unit-testing, go, synchronization, mutex

I am a newbie in GO and I had to use Mutex Lock/Unlock in my code to prevent concurrent access. But after I added the Lock/Unlock to my code, my tests started to run forever. I have simplified my use case and added the class and its test file. If I run the tests individually, all run fine. But if I run for the entire file, the first two are done, but the 3rd one runs forever. If I remove the Lock/Unlock, then the run are executed properly.

It would be great if someone could point out what I am doing wrong here.

Code under test:

```
package anything

import (
    "sync"
)

var maxLimit = 5
var Store = Cache{make([]string, 0)}
var mutex = new(sync.RWMutex)

type Cache struct {
    items []string
}

func (cache *Cache) Push(item string) {
    mutex.Lock()
    if len(cache.items) == maxLimit {
        cache.items = append(cache.items[:0], cache.items[1:]...)
    }
    cache.items = append(cache.items, item)
    mutex.Unlock()
}

func (cache *Cache) Get(content string) string {
    mutex.RLock()
    for _, item := range cache.items {
        if item == content {
            return content
        }
    }
    mutex.RUnlock()
    return ""
}
```

Test File:

```
package anything

import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

func TestPush_MoreThanTheMaxLimit_RemoveFirstItem(t *testing.T) {
    for i := 0; i <= maxLimit; i++ {
        item := strconv.Itoa(i)
        Store.Push(item)
    }
    var actual = Store.items[0]
    assert.Equal(t, "1", actual)
}

func TestGet_PresentInCache_ReturnsItem(t *testing.T) {
    Store.Push(strconv.Itoa(1))
    Store.Push(strconv.Itoa(3))

    var actual = Store.Get("1")
    assert.Equal(t, "1", actual)
}

func TestGet_NotPresentInCache_ReturnsNil(t *testing.T) {
    Store.Push(strconv.Itoa(1))
    Store.Push(strconv.Itoa(3))

    var actual = Store.Get("7")
    assert.Empty(t, actual)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `Cache.Get()` method finds the item, it returns without calling `mutex.RUnlock()`, so the mutex remains locked. Then calling `Cache.Get()` again will block because you can't lock an already locked mutex.

Instead unlock using [`defer`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements), so the mutex will get unlocked no matter how the function ends:

```
func (cache *Cache) Get(content string) string {
    mutex.RLock()
    defer mutex.RUnlock()
    for _, item := range cache.items {
        if item == content {
            return content
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Also consider adding the mutex to the `Cache` struct itself, because that mutex is ought to protect concurrent access to a `Cache` value. It's fine in your example, but if you were to create multiple values of `Cache`, a single mutex would be insufficient (would unnecessarily block access to all `Cache` values while it would be enough to block access to a single `Cache` being accessed). It's also a good idea to embed the mutex, see [When do you embed mutex in struct in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949467/when-do-you-embed-mutex-in-struct-in-go/44950096#44950096)

Comment: Silly mistake :( Totally forgot about the return statement. Thanks for pointing out the usage of `defer`.