# Mutex - global or local and idiomatic usage?

Tags: go, mutex

After reading the mutex examples on golang.org and stackoverflow, I'm still not sure about the declaration and idiomatic usage with anonymous functions. Therefore I've summarized a few examples.

Are examples A, B and C nearly equivalent or are there major differences that I don't notice?
I would prefer the global example "B". I guess if I'm careful with it, it's probably the simplest solution.

Or is there maybe a better approach to use mutex?

[This example on go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pn59l1M_EvG)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type MuContainer struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    data int
}

var mucglobal = &MuContainer{}

func main() {

    // A: Global declaration - working: adds 45
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(j int, mucf *MuContainer) {
            mucf.Lock()
            mucf.data += j
            mucf.Unlock()
        }(i, mucglobal)
    }

    // B: Global only - working: adds 45
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(j int) {
            mucglobal.Lock()
            mucglobal.data += j
            mucglobal.Unlock()
        }(i)
    }

    // C: Local declaration - working: adds 45
    muclocal := &MuContainer{}
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(j int, mucf *MuContainer) {
            mucf.Lock()
            mucf.data += j
            mucf.Unlock()
        }(i, muclocal)
    }

    // // D: Pointer to struct - not working: adds 0
    // // I guess because it points directly to the struct.
    // for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    //  go func(j int, mucf *MuContainer) {
    //      mucf.Lock()
    //      mucf.data += j
    //      mucf.Unlock()
    //  }(i, &MuContainer{})
    // }

    for {
        mucglobal.RLock()
        muclocal.RLock()
        fmt.Printf("global: %d / local: %d\n", mucglobal.data, muclocal.data)
        if mucglobal.data == 90 && muclocal.data == 45 {
            muclocal.RUnlock()
            mucglobal.RUnlock()
            break
        }
        muclocal.RUnlock()
        mucglobal.RUnlock()
    }
}
```

Comment: See related / possible duplicate: [When do you embed mutex in struct in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949467/when-do-you-embed-mutex-in-struct-in-go/44950096#44950096)

Comment: There is no substantial difference between A, B and C. You are probably overrating "idiomatic" here.

Comment: A and B are identical. C may or may not work  differently in real world code (depending on whether there's other code accessing the same package var), but in this code it's identical to A and B. D doesn't make any sense in this context, may or may not be valid in any other hypothetical context.

Comment: @Volker and Adrian Are there other methods that are more different? i'm using mutex for the first time and looking for a recommended start.

Comment: You are mixing up different things. A mutex is a mutex. Normaly you use a *sync.Mutex, not a mutex as mutexes must not be copied. Embeding a mutex is okay, but if you do not feel comfortable with mutextes, struct literals, and popinters: why not just use a simple (unembedded) field. You probably overthink this.

Comment: @Volker Thanks, you mean declaring e.g. in func main like `var mu *sync.Mutex` and than just `mu.Lock()` / `mu.Unlock()`. This would feel much better.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no idea what your code is trying to do or which problem you are trying to solve. Sometimes global or local variables are okay and then having a block `var ( xyzMu = new(sync.Mutex); xyz XYZ)` is fine. Mutex and variable protected by that mutex go side by side. Sometimes it's better to have the mutex as a field. If you use a field you can have a "normal" field or "embed" a mutex (your code embeds it). Empirically embedding is problematic for newcommers to the language. It really doesn't matter _how_ you do it if you do it _correctly_ .

Comment: Thank you for the example. Now I understand :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D is not working because you are creating a new struct for each iteration. In the end, you'll have 10 independent instances of `MuContainer`.

The first two options are semantically identical. The bottom line for those two is that each goroutine shares the same instance of the object, which happens to be a global var.

The second one is similar with the only difference being the object locked and updated happens to be a local var. Again, the goroutines are working on the same instance of the object.

So these are not really different from each other, and all three have their uses.