# Using a mutex within a struct in Go

Tags: go, struct, concurrency, mutex

I see in [Essential Go](https://www.programming-books.io/essential/go/) that using a mutex within a struct is not too straight-forward. To quote from the [Mutex Gotchas](https://www.programming-books.io/essential/go/mutex-gotchas-1c78058100ed4b45aab9461f69c05ecd#3968befb-6d13-46b8-819c-459f9df67793) page:

> **Don’t copy mutexes**
>
> A copy of `sync.Mutex` variable starts with the same state as original
> mutex but it is not the same mutex.
>
> It’s almost always a mistake to copy a `sync.Mutex` e.g. by passing it
> to another function or embedding it in a struct and making a copy of
> that struct.
>
> If you want to share a mutex variable, pass it as a pointer
> `*sync.Mutex`.

I'm not quite sure I fully understand exactly what's written. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949467/when-do-you-embed-mutex-in-struct-in-go) but still wasn't totally clear.

Taking the Essential Go example of a [Set](https://www.codeeval.dev/gist/2f0f3ca37296cade012f22c52b28547a), should I be using the mutex like this:

```
type StringSet struct {
    m map[string]struct{}
    mu            sync.RWMutex
}
```

or like this?

```
type StringSet struct {
    m map[string]struct{}
    mu            *sync.RWMutex
}
```

I tried both with the Delete() function within the example and they both work in the [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xHP0tTh5FDz).

```
// Delete removes a string from the set
func (s *StringSet) Delete(str string) {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()
    delete(s.m, str)
}
```

There will obviously be several instances of a 'Set', and hence each instance should have its own mutex. In such a case, is it preferable to use the mutex or a pointer to the mutex?

Comment: One mutex per resource. Don't copy it. You don't need a pointer in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the first method (a plain Mutex, not a pointer to a mutex), and pass around a `*StringSet` (pointer to your struct), not a plain `StringSet`.

In the code you shared in your playground ([that version](https://play.golang.org/p/xHP0tTh5FDz)) :

- `.Add()`, `.Exists()` and `.Strings()` should acquire the lock,
- otherwise your code fits a regular use of structs and mutexes in go.

---

The "Don't copy mutexes" gotcha would apply if you manipulated plain `StringSet` structs :

```
var setA StringSet
setA.Add("foo")
setA.Add("bar")

func buggyFunction(s StringSet) {
  ...
}


// the gotcha would occur here :
var setB = setA
// or here :
buggyFunction(setA)
```

In both cases above : you would create a copy of *the complete struct*

so `setB`, for example, would manipulate the same underlying `map[string]struct{}` mapping as `setA`, but the mutex would not be shared : calling `setA.m.Lock()` wouldn't prevent modifying the mapping from `setB`.

Comment: Thanks for the example of the 'gotcha'. I must admit my 'Java-trained' brain prevented me from seeing this. As the NewSet() function returns a pointer to the Set, and all Set methods use pointers, I guess a pointer to a mutex would be redundant indeed.

Answer (score -1):

If you go the first way, i.e.

```
type StringSet struct {
    m map[string]struct{}
    mu            sync.RWMutex
}
```

any accidental or intentional assignment/copy of a struct value will create a new mutex, but the underlying map `m` will be the same (because [maps are essentially pointers](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/30/if-a-map-isnt-a-reference-variable-what-is-it)). As a result, it will be possible to modify/access the map concurrently without locking. Of course, if you strictly follow a rule "thou shalt not copy a set", that won't happen, but it doesn't make much sense to me.

TL;DR: definitely the second way.

Comment: The OP's method `Delete` is a pointer receiver - so the mutex will not be copied. So, as you say, don't copy it elsewhere.

Comment: @colm.anseo that sounds like a weird constraint for a set type. And someone will someday violate it for sure.

Comment: Most Go code will use a mutex value to ease in struct value initialization and also prevent accidentally sharing mutexes. If a value receiver is used or the struct value is copied, `go vet` (which runs on any test) will pickup the incorrect usage.

Comment: Also, "copying" a set - with the same backing map - seems ripe for more bugs.

Comment: @colm.anseo I had the same thought at first, until I realized that standard Go containers (maps and slices) behave the same way, and everyone is already used to it. So why would passing a map behave differently from passing a map with a mutex?

Comment: I think this all boils down to how one would copy `StringSet`. While copying a pointer to a mutex works - copying the map (pointer) is not what one would want IMHO. A `dst := CopyStringSet(src)` function would solve all the inner logic: lock access to `src` map while copying to new map; create new mutex (pointer or not)